# Logic for a booking system to show available slots based on user input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to figure out the backend logic to build a car booking system where a user will choose a date and enter the amount of time he needs the car for. Then the system will generate available slots with a `start` and `end` time.  Every time user returns the car the owner will wash the car for `10 minutes` so the next slot's `start` time will be previous `end + 10 minutes`.

For example user books the car on `2022-09-04` and books the slot for `30 minutes`. Now the available slots will be `12:00 AM-12:30 AM` and the next slot will be `12:40 AM-1:10 AM` and so on for the whole day. The user can choose whichever slots he wants.

Here is the UI if it helps.

Before user input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiM4t.jpg

After user input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6nGO.jpg

If another user wants to book a slot for `20 minutes` I want existing available slots to adjust with that time without conflicting with the booked slots.

I have generated initial slots(no slot is booked yet) in the front end for `30minutes` duration.
I will move this in the backend after I figure out the logic. I am using `Nodejs` and `mongodb` in the backend.

I haven't worked with date-time before that's why kinda struggling.

```
import { addMinutes} from "date-fns";

const availableSlots = [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      start: new Date(date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString(),//date=user selected date
      end: "",
    },
  ];
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputValue = parseInt(e.target.time.value);
    if (inputValue > 0) {
      let end;
      let start;
      const timeToWash = 10
      for (let i = 0; i < 1440 / (inputValue + timeToWash); i++) {
        if (i < 1) {
          end = addMinutes(new Date(availableSlots[i].start), inputValue);
          end = end.toISOString();
          availableSlots[i] = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            start: availableSlots[0].start,
            end: end,
          };
        } else {
          start = addMinutes(
            new Date(availableSlots[i - 1].start),
            inputValue + timeToWash 
          );
          start = start.toISOString();
          end = addMinutes(new Date(start), inputValue);
          end = end.toISOString();
          availableSlots[i] = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            start: start,
            end: end,
          };
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is it required to have default slots of 30 mins. I was thinking it would be simpler to start with a single slot of `00:00 - 23:59` and then every time someone makes a booking you split it into 2 free slots. So after booking at noon for 40 mins + 10 mins washing you divide the slot into `00:00 - 11:50` and `12:50 - 23:59`.

Comment: 30 minutes is not default I just gave it initially. It will be what user inputs. Available slots will be shown on ui after user gives the input. So if user gives 40min, i will show availbale slots on ui `12.40-1.20`, `1.30-2.10` and so on for whole day.